# while True and if statement printing the same calculation

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, python-3.8, converters

I am working on a feet to inches converter that is actually very easy to create, as I have done it before. But this time, I am required to use a while loop. Basically, if the number of feet is equal to 0, it shoud print 'the program has finished successfully.' If the number of feet is greater than or equal to 1, the code will continue to make calculation until user input of 0 quits the script. My issue is that when I test quit the script, it prints:
"0 feet = 0 inches
the program has finished successfully."
I just want it to print the termination message, not 0 feet = 0 inches. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
def feet_to_inches(feet):
return 12 * feet

feet = int(input('Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): '))
inches = feet_to_inches(feet)
print(f'{feet} feet = {inches} inches')

while True:
    if feet == 0:
        print('The program has finished successfully.')
        break
    ...       
    if feet >= 1:
        feet = int(input('Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): '))
        inches = feet_to_inches(feet)
        print(f'{feet} feet = {inches} inches')
        continue
```

Comment: You always take the input, do the conversion, print the conversion, *and then* you hit the condition to end the program…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added comments for the changes that are needed

Few things:

- Indentation was wrong (maybe it's StackOverflow)
- Since you will require user input to decide whether to exit the loop, you can ask for input in the loop and then decide what to do
- continue is not required in the end

Suggested code:

```
def feet_to_inches(feet):
    return 12 * feet #indentation error

while True:
    feet = int(input('Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): ')) #moving input inside the while loop
    inches = feet_to_inches(feet)
    if feet == 0:
        print('The program has finished successfully.')
        break     
    elif feet >= 1:
        # feet = int(input('Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): '))#not required
        # inches = feet_to_inches(feet) #not required
        print(f'{feet} feet = {inches} inches')
        # continue #this is not required
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 1
1 feet = 12 inches
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 2
2 feet = 24 inches
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 3
3 feet = 36 inches
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 0
The program has finished successfully.
```

Comment: This was really helpful! I finally have it printing correctly, thanks for your input on my issue!

Answer (score 0):

See the below code that also checks default case.

```
def feet_to_inches(feet):
    return 12 * feet # Please be aware your indentation error

while True:
    feet = int(input('Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): '))
    inches = feet_to_inches(feet)
    if feet == 0:
        print('The program has finished successfully.')
        break     
    elif feet >= 1:
        print(f'{feet} feet = {inches} inches')
    else:
      print(f'Please provide a positive value')
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 2
2 feet = 24 inches
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 1
1 feet = 12 inches
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): -8
Please provide a positive value
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 23
23 feet = 276 inches
Enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): 0
The program has finished successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternate code structure for the feet-to-inches converter.

```
while True:
    feet = int(input('Please enter the number of feet (or 0 to end): '))
    if feet == 0:
        print('Program ended successfully.')
        break
    elif feet < 0:
        print('Please enter a positive value.')
        continue
    else:
        feet_to_inches = 12 * feet
        print('%d feet converts to %d inches'%(feet, feet_to_inches))
```